# Visualforce page can't find my method?

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller

Firstly, let me apologize in advance for my extreme naivete' in this matter. I'm quite new to VF and could not find documentation to cover what should be an incredibly simply issue.

I have a quick class I've written (below)

```
public class TestContactRole {
    public static string getReturnOppID(){
        String OppID;
        OppID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        system.debug(OppID);
        return OppID;
    }
}
```

I'm wanting this code to return the Opportunity record's Id button when a VF enabled button is clicked on a related list under the Opportunity. My VF code is listed below.

```
<apex:page lightningStylesheets="true" controller="TestContactRole">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:form >
            <apex:commandButton value="HelloWorld" action="{!ReturnOppID}"/>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

**My VF page isn't finding the class.** I have 100% code coverage (hard not to), and the class is active in my sandbox. Are there any immediate thoughts anyone might be having here?

Answer (score 4):

"value" attributes always map to get/set methods, while "action" methods always refer to the exact method name.

```
<apex:outputText value="{!returnOppId}" ...
```

Will call:

```
public String getReturnOppId() { ...
```

Conversely:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!returnOppId}" ...
```

Will call:

```
public PageReference returnOppId() { ...
```

In addition, in order for your page to find the controller, you must specify the controller or extensions attribute:

```
<apex:page controller="TestContactRole" ...
```

... or ...

```
<apex:page extensions="TestContactRole" standardController="SomeSObjectType" ...
```

If you use the latter method, you also need to include a `standardController`. Also, if you do this, your controller has to have a single-parameter constructor that accepts an ApexPages.StandardController:

```
public class TestContactRole {
  ApexPages.StandardController ctrl;
  public TestContactRole(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    ctrl = controller;
  } ...
```

Which you can then use to get the ID value:

```
public void doSomething() {
  Id oppId = (Id)ctrl.getRecordId();
  ...
```

There's a third mode of operation for Visualforce pages, too, when you specify a `recordSetVar`, you need to change the controller's `ApexPages.StandardController` to `ApexPages.StandardSetController`.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for the prompt replay! I was expecting to wait a while. One question I've encountered however is that I'm now returning the following error - 'Formula Expression is required on the action attributes.' The only relevant change I've made was to the adjustment in naming my method. I've left the "Static" reference in the method declaration as the test method is also static.

Comment: @Drewd25 the attribute must be exactly like `action="{!methodname}"`. Make sure there's no extra spaces or characters outside the `{!...}` area.

Comment: <apex:commandButton value="HelloWorld" action="{!ReturnOppID}"/>. My method declaration is identical. I did retain the "Static" property on the method. Is this incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Remove static keyword and instead of `getReturnOppID`, name it as `ReturnOppID`, because, it is a method to be called and not a property.

```
public class TestContactRole {
    public string ReturnOppID(){
        String OppID;
        OppID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        system.debug(OppID);
        return OppID;
    }
}
```

Refer [Building a Custom Controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_custom.htm)